# How i can limit results by frequency of appearance in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch index "fruit" there are the following documents:

```
{"name": "Apple", "basket": [1,2]},
{"name": "Pineapple", "basket": [1,2]},
{"name": "Orange", "basket": [2,3]},
{"name": "Watermelon", "basket": [3]},
{"name": "Mango", "basket": [4,5]},
{"name": "Kiwi", "basket": [4,5]},
{"name": "Pear", "basket": [6]}
```

I would like to get a result of documents that have a basket of fruit, but only 1 of them maximum. So if the above were my whole index, I would want it to return:

```
{"name": "Apple", "basket": [1,2]},
{"name": "Orange", "basket": [2,3]},
{"name": "Watermelon", "basket": [3]},
{"name": "Kiwi", "basket": [4,5]},
{"name": "Pear", "basket": [6]}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a single query in elastic? 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what is your basket contains and can u explains your output for above dataset

Comment: Not clear enough about the results you expect

Comment: you want to aggregate (group by) basket right? We need your mappings + explein us witch document we have to keep (using a tophits) for each of the basket aggregation.